# select unique row as per latest created_at time

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my query:

```
SELECT br.employee_id AS rat_id,
       br.rating_comment,
       br.created_at,
       br.id
FROM employee_followers
LEFT JOIN employee_ratings AS br ON employee_followers. employee_id = br.employee_id
WHERE employee_followers.employee_id IN
    (SELECT `employee_id`
     FROM employee_followers
     WHERE user_id =32)
GROUP BY br.id
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

**what I am getting:**

```
rat_id    rating_comment        created_at              id
18        superb developer      2016-02-19 18:26:54     82
9         james to manoj-joshi  2016-02-19 16:42:17     84
50        james to prem         2016-02-19 13:05:30     83
50        pinal to prem         2016-02-19 12:20:00     73
50        prem to premal-joshi  2016-02-19 11:40:52     78
18        prem to mukund        2016-02-19 11:21:52     77
18        pinal to mukund       2016-02-18 11:37:00     76
9         mukund rate to mitesh 2016-02-15 22:34:14     51
9         Not a bad.            2016-02-10 00:16:31     45
9         sda                   2016-02-08 01:36:33     39
```

**what I want:**

```
rat_id    rating_comment        created_at              id
18        superb developer      2016-02-19 18:26:54     82
9         james to manoj-joshi  2016-02-19 16:42:17     84
50        james to prem         2016-02-19 13:05:30     83
```

Comment: nothing new happen same output again.

Comment: SELECT br.employee_id AS rat_id,
       br.rating_comment,
       br.created_at,
       br.id
FROM employee_followers
LEFT JOIN employee_ratings AS br ON employee_followers. employee_id = br.employee_id
WHERE employee_followers.employee_id IN
    (SELECT `employee_id`
     FROM employee_followers
     WHERE user_id =32)
GROUP BY rat_id
ORDER BY created_at DESC

Comment: i also tried this but it fetch first record of particular rat_id which is not having letest created_at time. mean in 9 rat_id it shows  9  sda  2016-02-08 01:36:33  39 beacause it is first record in employee)rating table

Comment: SELECT br.employee_id AS rat_id, br.rating_comment, br.created_at, br.id FROM employee_followers LEFT JOIN employee_ratings AS br ON employee_followers. employee_id = br.employee_id WHERE employee_followers.employee_id IN (SELECT employee_id FROM employee_followers WHERE user_id =32) GROUP BY rat_id ORDER BY ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: still displaying first record of perticular rat_id which comes in table first.

Comment: SELECT br.employee_id AS rat_id, br.rating_comment, br.created_at, br.id FROM employee_followers LEFT JOIN employee_ratings AS br ON employee_followers. employee_id = br.employee_id WHERE employee_followers.employee_id IN (SELECT employee_id FROM employee_followers WHERE user_id =32) GROUP BY rat_id ORDER BY br.created_at DESC

Comment: Telling us what you want without telling us what you have. Decorum prohibits me from saying what i think about that

Comment: strawberry sorry for in convince i am having two tables one is employee_followers and other is emplyee_ratings . first every single employee(a) can follow multiple users(b,c,d), after following them the employee or users(a)  who follows other  users(b,c,d), can see letest comment regarding followed user

Comment: hey Priyanshu thanks for your help. as i say in employee_rating table there were many records of particular employee_id so it gives me first records of table not latest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT rat_id,rating_comment, MAX(created_at) AS created, id FROM (
SELECT br.employee_id AS rat_id,
       br.rating_comment,
       br.created_at,
       br.id
FROM employee_followers
LEFT JOIN employee_ratings AS br ON employee_followers. employee_id = br.employee_id
WHERE employee_followers.employee_id IN
    (SELECT `employee_id`
     FROM employee_followers
     WHERE user_id =32)
GROUP BY br.id
ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS temp GROUP BY temp.rat_id
```

Comment: This would only work if full group by sql mode is not enabled. Luckily mysql decided to have it enabled by default in the newer versions. Btw, it is against the mysql standard.

Comment: thanks vipin jain your ans giving me desire output :) thank's  a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want only the latest record per `employee_id`. You can use a derived table to get the maximum date, then join again to get all fields from `employee_ratings` table for this date:

```
SELECT er.employee_id AS rat_id,
       er.rating_comment,
       er.created_at,
       er.id
FROM employee_followers AS ef
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT employee_id, MAX(created_at) AS max_date
   FROM employee_ratings
   GROUP BY employee_id
) AS emp_max ON ef.employee_id = emp_max.employee_id 
LEFT JOIN employee_ratings AS er 
   ON emp_max.employee_id = er.employee_id AND
      emp_max.max_date = er.max_date
WHERE user_id = 32
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

I have also removed `GROUP BY br.id` that seems to be redundant in the context of the query. Also `IN` operator can be replaced by `user_id = 32` since you are selecting from the same table.

Comment: tried your ans also but displays all records as first (what i get) table

Comment: @AMITJOSHI Giorgos' solution is definitely the right approach, so pls try to fix the query yourself, don't just wait around to be presented with a copy-paste solution!

Comment: shadow i tried since 2 days after that i ask here for expert. thanks for your reviews.

Comment: @AMITJOSHI Can you provide the sample data that the result you get is derived from?

Comment: thanks for all of you concern i got my desire ouput with help of vipin jain http://stackoverflow.com/users/2153834/vipin-jain.